# how to get the traversing path in tree like structure loading from XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tree structure like below.

[image]

when i travese through parent to child i want the full path like :
Chemistry->Physical chemistry->Particle theory->Particle theory on clicking the particular node.
and when we go back or click the Physical chemistry then path will return like that :
Chemistry->Physical chemistry

how can we do that.
i am using the following function.

```
function getParents(id) 
{
  var parents = $("#" + id).parents("ul");
  var selector = "";
  for (var i = parents.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    //alert($(parents[i]).find('li').find('span').find('a').html());
    selector += $(parents[i]).find('li').parent().find('span').find('a').html() + " > ";
  }

  //selector += "#" + id;
  $('#breadcrumbs').html(selector);
  //return selector;
}
```

but it goes to wrong direction.

Comment: What's the code you're using? Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a prime example for a recursive function.

```
function getBreadcrumbs(a) {
    var path = $(a).text(),
        $parent = $(a).parents("li").eq(1).find("a:first");

    if ($parent.length == 1) {
        path = getBreadcrumbs($parent) + " > " + path;
    }
    return path;
}

$("ul a").click(function () {
    $("#breadcrumbs").text( getBreadcrumbs(this) );
});
```

See it working over here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/GFfyg/

Comment: Helped me today Thanks!